# Different developement and production environment production logs when they shouldn't

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, logback, spring-logback

I am working on a 9 yo Spring application with log generation done with Logback.

Logging is working fine in development environment, but when we switch to our production environment, logs are still being written until the "Application started in ...ms". After that, nothing else will ever been written.

After some digging, I noticed that our logback is not built in our war but is set into Tomcat libs. It made me think that we could have override properties disabling our logging settings. Problem is, the developer who worked on that is not in my company anymore, so I'm basically searching blindly.
Do you think I am right with my first assumption? Where should I search for some conf files overriding my application.properties?

Here is our application.properties logging settings:

```
logging.config= classpath:./extranet_config/logback.xml
logging.level.com.sun.mail= trace
logging.exception-conversion-word=
logging.pattern.console=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger - %msg %n
logging.pattern.file=.%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level - %msg %n
logging.pattern.level=%5p
```

And the logback:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS_FOLDER" value="C://log/Extranet/logs" />
    <property name="LOGS_TO_COLLECT_FOLDER" value="C://log/Extranet/logs-to-collect" />

    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5level | %-22thread | %-12logger | %msg %n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="log-file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
        <file>${LOGS_FOLDER}/extranet.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_TO_COLLECT_FOLDER}/extranet.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
            </fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5level | %-22thread | %-12logger | %m %throwable{0}%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="troubleshooting-file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
        <file>${LOGS_FOLDER}/extranet-troubleshooting.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS_FOLDER}/extranet-troubleshooting.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5level | %-22thread | %-12logger | %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="Application" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="QueryLogger" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="AOPLogger" level="TRACE"/>    

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="log-file" />
        <appender-ref ref="troubleshooting-file" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Note: those two files are identical in prod and in development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, our logback classpath was not read the same way on both servers, we changed them and everything is working properly now.